# dailyReturn: Error in to_period(xx, period = on.opts[[period]], ...) : unsupported type

Tags: r, quantmod

This is the some of the output

```
 head(prices)
           SASINI  KQ      NMG      BBK     CFC      ICDCI   KCB     SCBK 
2011-09-07 "10.30" "29.25" "136.00" "12.00" " 46.00" "14.95" "19.45" "199"
2011-09-08 "10.80" "31.00" "139.00" "12.00" "  0.00" "15.55" "19.45" "199"
2011-09-09 "10.70" "30.25" "138.00" "11.95" " 46.50" "16.35" "19.4"  "199"
2011-09-12 "10.45" "30.75" "  0.00" "11.95" " 45.25" "16.95" "19.15" "194"
2011-09-13 "10.95" "30.50" "138.00" "12.00" " 45.25" "16.60" "19.25" "195"
2011-09-14 "11.45" "31.00" "138.00" "11.95" " 46.00" "16.50" "19.5"  "194"
```

when I apply this code

```
SASINI= dailyReturn(prices$SASINI,type="log",leading=TRUE)
```

it returns this error which i dont understand

> SASINI=dailyReturn(prices$SASINI,type="log",leading=TRUE) Error in
>   to_period(xx, period = on.opts[[period]], ...) :    unsupported type

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: your xts object has been wrongly formatted. you have a character matrix instead of a numeric matrix. You need to show some more code on how you got to this point. read the post on [how to create reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of the variable you are using, you use mode() function for that, and I sugest you to look at the documentation of the periodReturn function, make sure your 'x' is a supported type for the dailyReturn function; you can access the page [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/quantmod/versions/0.4-13/topics/periodReturn).

Comment: thank you for your reply but i have converted those daily closing prices of the mentioned companies as an xts object